# Hibernate Null values for @CollectionOfElements

Tags: hibernate, collections

I'm mapping a set of attributes to my entity using @CollectionOfElements. The goal here is to be able to provide a meta data list that can be used in a query to pull specific entries.

I've figured out the mapping and how to run the queries I want. The problem is that hibernate won't persist null values!

```
    @CollectionOfElements()
    @JoinTable(name = "plan_attribute", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "plan_id"))
    @MapKey(columns = @Column(name = "attribute_name", nullable = false, length = 255))
    @Column(name = "attribute_value", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public Map getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public void addAttribute(String name, String value) {
        this.attributes.put(name, value);
    }
```

Eg. object.addAttribute("someName", null); will not be persisted

Anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this without implementing a key/value pair entity for the sole purpose of persisting these values?

Regards,

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? I wonder if this could be related to [HHH-772](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-772).

Comment: Hibernate 3.3.2.GA, so yes - it looks like that bug applies. I was able to workaround the issue by explicitly setting null values as a '*' character which actually works quite well and fits better than 'null' for my use-cases.

Comment: Since the problem is solved, it would be a good idea to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I stumbled across this question because it was marked as unanswered. You should really close it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the OP comments:

> Hibernate 3.3.2.GA, so yes - it looks
>   like that bug applies. I was able to
>   workaround the issue by explicitly
>   setting null values as a '*' character
>   which actually works quite well and
>   fits better than 'null' for my
>   use-cases.

This answer should get this off the list of unanswered questions until a close vote is made.